# Using this in lifecycle hook created from composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a problem with typescript in Vue 3.

1. Get Data from Itunes everytime prop 'query' is modified. (format: [{}, {},{},...]
2. Call Function to filter unused information from fetch

When I call function (this function will filter objects to simplify code) in fetch, it throws an Error:

```
Property 'filterData' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

My Code:

```
<template>
    <div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onUpdated } from 'vue';

interface Song {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    nameT: string;
    cover?: string;
    preview: string;
}

interface SongFromITunes {
    artistId: number;
    artistName: string;
    trackName: string;
    previewUrl: string;
    artworkUrl100?: string;
}

export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            list: [] as Array<Song>
        };
    },
    props: {
        query: String
    },
    methods: {
        filterData({
            artistId: id,
            artistName: name,
            trackName: nameT,
            artworkUrl100: cover,
            previewUrl: preview
        }: SongFromITunes): Song {
            return { id, name, nameT, cover, preview };
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
        onUpdated(() => {
            const { query } = props;
            if (query != null) {
                fetch(
                    `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${encodeURI(
                        query
                    )}&limit=10&entity=musicTrack`
                )
                    .then((resolve) => resolve.json())
                    .then((data) => data.results.map((item: SongFromITunes) => this.filterData(item));
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Answer (score 6):

I found your question really interesting.

From the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#setup-component-option) it's clear `this` cannot be used inside `setup()` as the Vue instance doesn't exist yet.

But in the case of lifecycle hooks you are passing the callback which must be sometime later attached to the new Vue instance

[Docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks) : *These lifecycle hook registration functions can only be used synchronously during `setup()`, since they rely on internal global state to locate the current active instance (the component instance whose `setup()` is being called right now).*

So it seems <s>the right way to do would be</s> *it would be easy* if Vue just used `bind` and bound the callback to the instance. However it's not the case it seems...

Solution for you is to move `filterData` from `methods` into `setup()`

```js
    setup(props) {
        let filterData = function({
            artistId: id,
            artistName: name,
            trackName: nameT,
            artworkUrl100: cover,
            previewUrl: preview
        }: SongFromITunes): Song {
            return { id, name, nameT, cover, preview };
        }

        onUpdated(() => {
            const { query } = props;
            if (query != null) {
                fetch(
                    `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${encodeURI(
                        query
                    )}&limit=10&entity=musicTrack`
                )
                    .then((resolve) => resolve.json())
                    .then((data) => data.results.map((item: SongFromITunes) => filterData(item));
            }
        });

        return { filterData }
    }
```

## Update

I was really curious about the reasons behind this because I feel hooks are inherently bound to the instance and probably many people will expect `this` is available in callbacks. So I asked on Vue discord and received following explanation (thanks Vaage#9161):

*If we bind the lifecycle hooks in setup to the instance, it would only cause confusion and encourage antipatterns.
You make a choice, options api, or composition api. If you choose composition api, there is nothing interesting for you on `this`. Everything is contained in the `setup` closure.
If we added it, typescript inference would be harder to implement, and people will start using the options api in combination with it.*

### Message of the day

**Don't mix composition api and options api**

Comment: "Message of the day": Exactly, decide what to use in the project and stick to it!

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not accessible from the setup function because the component has not been created yet. You need to define `filterData` inside setup as well.

[Here's the relevant documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-component-properties)